# Convert comma seperated object into an INT to do math on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform math on some objects I am having trouble understanding how to accomplish what I need. Lets say I have these two objects:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var boom = [2,3,1,4,5,2,5,6];
result = [-1,-1,2,0,0,4,2,2];
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to subtract the individual numbers from each other between the commas to obtain the `result`. Is there a method that does this? I tried using `split(',')` to remove the commas but it said `split()` is not available on objects.

Comment: Why not use a for loop and loop trough the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to loop over one array and subtract the values in the other array:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var boom = [2,3,1,4,5,2,5,6];

var result = test.map(function(item, index){ return item - boom[index]; });

console.log(result); // [-1, -1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2]
```

If you don't like functional programming you can do it with regular for:

```
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
  result.push(test[i]-boom[i]);
}
```

Comment: By 6 whole seconds :)).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var result = test.map(function(v,k){return v - boom[k];});
```

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQpAM/)

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to using `map` is using a simple `for loop`:

```
function subtract(arr1, arr2){
  var out = [];
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
    out[i] = arr1[i] - arr2[i];
  }
  return out;
}

var subtracted = subtract(test, boom); // [-1, -1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYx6X/1/).